# Fixed height inside container-fluid and row Bootstrap Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, height, containers

I only use bootstrap gris system on my page.
I'm trying to fix the height of an element inside a countainer and in a row.

```
<div class="container-fluid firstcontainer">
    <div class="row">
        <header scroll ng-class="document.body.scrollTop > 100 ? 'fullNav' : ''" class="header col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <a href="#" class="header__icon" id="header__icon" ng-click="withSidebar = !withSidebar"></a>
            <a href="#" class="header__logo"><span>MS94</span></a>
            <nav class="menu">
                <a href="#">Accueil</a>
                <a href="#">Voilà</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="intro" class="intro">
            <span class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1>Un titre qui envoi du steack haché</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste nulla, rerum! Ratione magni sed, esse, placeat consequuntur animi repellat ullam praesentium, voluptatibus ipsam error architecto vitae distinctio porro! Excepturi, omnis!</p>
            </span>
        </section>
        <section class="brand col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><img src="img/logo/1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2"><img src="img/logo/2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2"><img src="img/logo/3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2"><img src="img/logo/4.jpg"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I try to make the block intro to take 70% of the height and the brand block 30%;
The class firstcontainer juste have a height: 100% to take all the place. 
But intro and brand don't take care of the height in the css

http://jsfiddle.net/zewxxux7/1/

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: On the `.intro` you have a `padding: 15% 10%`. I'm guessing you expect that to use 15 + 15 = 30% of the height. However the percentage unit is based on the width of the screen instead of the height. I think this is the first issue you need to solve.

Comment: I've added the padding to force height as a temporary solution. But I'll not use this if I found how to force the height without the padding

Comment: Every element up to the `.intro` needs to have `height: 100%` set. The `.row` doesn't have that. Add `.firstcontainer > .row { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Thank you that was the issue